# LIKE clause. in python connectors mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, count, sql-like

I try to get the number of movies that include the word "the" in their title, by LIKE clause. in Python connectors MySQL:

```py
word='the'
query = """ SELECT COUNT(title) from movies WHERE title LIKE '%%%s%%' """ % (word,)
cursor.execute(query)
    
# error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT COUNT(title) from movies WHERE title LIKE '%the%'' at line 1
    
p = "the"
query = ("SELECT COUNT(title) from movies WHERE title LIKE", ("%" + p + "%",))
cursor.execute(query,(p,))
    
# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: You haven't put any binding parameters into the second query. `, ("%" + p + "%",)` doesn't just tag it on to the end of the query, it unpacks the argument into a placeholder. The first query is open to injection and should be totally avoided

Comment: Your problem is in extra ',' somewhere in the code. When you do `object, object` in python, then it implicitly transformed into tuple `(object, object)`, so some extra ',' transformed some part of your code into tuple. Ensure that your query is a string and that you pass arguments in cursor.execute correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You would do:

```py
query = "SELECT COUNT(title) from movies WHERE title LIKE CONCAT('%', %s, '%')";
cursor.execute(query, (word,))
```

This uses a proper prepared statement to pass the variables to the query, so the code is safe from SQL injection, and more efficient.

You could also do the concatenation of wildcard on application side:

```py
query = "SELECT COUNT(title) from movies WHERE title LIKE %s";
cursor.execute(query, ('%' + word + '%',))
```